# Is there a way on server 2019 to logoff an RD user session in a command file

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2019, auto-login

On Server 2008 have an assembler routine that was set as the final command on a users start command batch file. They logged into the RD session, the batch file ran, executed an application and when they exited the application the routine would logoff the session automatically. Sadly the routine does not function on 2019. Is there a known command/routine that can automatically logoff a user RD session from a batch file?

Comment: If the batch file is running as the user the `shutdown /l` does that.

Comment: How about just running `logoff` from the cmd/batch file?